# Categorising a list into two separate lists by type

Tags: list, prolog

I'm still fairly new to Prolog and I've been having difficulties with an exercise involving lists: given a list of arbitrary data, separate the list into two lists - one containing integer values, and one containing real number values, then disregard any other items in the original list.

I've written the following so far:

```
isInteger(I, IntegerListHead):-
    integer(I),
    IntegerListHead is I.

isFloat(F, FloatListHead):-
    float(F),
    FloatListHead is F.

splitList([]).
splitList([H|T], [IntHead|IntList],[FloatHead|FloatList]):-
    isInteger(H, IntHead),
    isFloat(H, FloatHead),
    splitList(T, IntList, FloatList).
```

However, I'm not sure why I get certain errors:

```
?- splitList([1, 2.5, 6, 7.0, -1, -0.5], I, F).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: splitList/3 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

The usual suspects for this error don't seem to be the case, but maybe I've missed something?

Edit: When I reloaded the file and ran it a second time I got the following:

```
?- splitList([1, 2.5, 6, 7.0, -1, -0.5], I, F).
false.
```

Comment: Your `splitList` predicate has one argument for the base case clause, but 3 arguments for the recursive clause. That won't work. You need 3 for the base case as well and it needs to provide corresponding values for the other two (in this case, wouldn't `[]` be appropriate?). Your error looks like Prolog didn't define the 3-argument predicate, so you must not have loaded the code you're showing properly.

Comment: Your error message does contain a typo: You are calling `splitList/1` which is a simple fact, but you get an error about `splitList/3`. That's impossible.

Comment: Ah, apologies - I copied the incorrect line. Let me edit that quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case needs to be more complete. It defines what the split lists look like if the unified list is empty. So the base case should be:

```
splitList([], [], []).   % Split lists are empty iff the unified list is empty
```

Your recursive clause tries to do everything at once but makes a conjunction of the integer versus float test on the head of the list, resulting in a necessarily false condition. In other words, the following is true only if `H` is both a float and an integer:

```
isInteger(H, IntHead),
isFloat(H, FloatHead)
```

You can split that out using another clause. The resulting predicate will look like this:

```
splitList([], [], []).
splitList([H|T], [IntHead|IntList], FloatList):-
    isInteger(H, IntHead),
    splitList(T, IntList, FloatList).
splitList([H|T], IntList, [FloatHead|FloatList]):-
    isFloat(H, FloatHead),
    splitList(T, IntList, FloatList).
```

Finally, you really don't need `isInteger` or `isFloat`. They only make unnecessary "copies" of the values after confirming their type. You only need to test `H`:

```
splitList([], [], []).
splitList([H|T], [H|IntList], FloatList):-
    integer(H),
    splitList(T, IntList, FloatList).
splitList([H|T], IntList, [H|FloatList]):-
    float(H),
    splitList(T, IntList, FloatList).
```

---

As @CapelliC indicated, this will just fail if your list has non-numbers in it. You can take the following approach for more generality, which will skip the non-numeric elements. It is easily modified to retain the non-numeric elements in a separate list.

```
splitList([], [], []).
splitList([H|T], IntList, FloatList):-
    (   integer(H)
    ->  IntList = [H|Ints],
        FloatList = Floats
    ;   float(H)
    ->  IntList = Ints,
        FloatList = [H|Floats]
    ;   IntList = Ints,
        FloatList = Floats
    ),
    splitList(T, Ints, Floats).
```

Comment: don't you forget to skip elements that are not integers or float ?

Comment: @CapelliC indeed, good catch! I was trying to keep it simple by assuming the list was "well-behaved". :)